# How does Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics.FileLoggingSession work?

Tags: logging, windows-runtime, winjs, windows-error-reporting

I want to constantly write a continuing logfile that contains all messages raised. It sounds like FileLoggingSession is the right way to do so. How does it work? Is it saving the logfile internal or only when calling

```
fileLoggingSession.closeAndSaveToFileAsync().done();
```

?
This is also closing the session so not suitable for my case. I want to append messages to the log file in realtime.

Using Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync with Promises doesn't work because to many messages are raised, so I'm getting an exception.

Is FileLoggingSession suitable for this scenario and how do I access or save a file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Logging output is one or more files that is being generated, and client is responsible for saving them.
When a log file is generated, the [LogFileGenerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.foundation.diagnostics.fileloggingsession.logfilegenerated) event gets raised and you need to save the file (Provided in event args).

MSDN says:

> This event is raised when the session rolls over from one log file to the next. Your event handler must save the log file if you want a copy of it because the log file will be deleted or overwritten immediately after this event returns.
>
> This event is not raised for the last log file because the last log file does not roll over. Use CloseAndSaveToFileAsync to access the last log file.

Comment: `// This handler is called by the FileLoggingSession instance when a log
   
 // file reaches a size of 256MB. When FileLoggingSession calls this handler, 

    // it's effectively giving the developer a chance to own the log file.`
Is there a way to access these files without waiting that logfile has reached 256MB without closing via "CloseAndSaveToFileAsync"?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Is FileLoggerSession present when restarting app? How to save on crash/error? CloseAndSaveToFileAsync might be cut off when defined in WinJS.Application.onerror , right?

Comment: I'm don't have much experience with FileLoggerSession but I guess you need to call the CloseAndSaveToFileAsync whenever app is being terminated/suspended/restarted or whenever a crash occurs; and get a new instance on resume/restart again.